# Java: getSlope cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am having trouble with printing getSlope() to the console, with any values I plug in for (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2), Java ends up dividing by zero every time I run the program.

Slope class:

```
public class Slope {
    private int x1;
    private int x2;
    private int y1;
    private int y2;

    public Slope(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        a = x1;
        b = x2;
        c = y1;
        d = x2;
    }

    public void setSlope(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        x1 = a;
        x2 = b;
        y1 = c;
        y2 = d;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return (x1 - x2);
    }

    public int getY() {
        return (y1 - y2);
    }

    public void sayThis() {
        System.out.println(getX()/getY());
    }
}
```

testSlope Class:

```
public class testSlope {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Slope slope = new Slope(10, 5, 1, 2);
        slope.sayThis(); 
    }
    //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    //    at Slope.getSlope(Slope.java:22)
    //    at Slope.sayThis(Slope.java:26)
    //    at testSlope.main(testSlope.java:5)

}
```

Comment: Typo: `System.out.println(getSlope())` + 2 different questions being asked

Comment: Just another comment: please respect the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html): Classes always start with an uppercase letter and fields / variables should have meaningful names instead of `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

Comment: @JohnStobben you edited the question in such a way that the original problem des not longer appear. I suggest a rollback to the old version.

Comment: What exactly does your title have to do with your question?

Comment: @EJP could you rollback the question to the first revision? I would take care of the rest from there on.

Comment: @Turing85 Why? Let him fix his own question. It's not your problem.

Comment: @EJP OP got his answer already, so I think OP will not do anything. For the purpose of documentation, it would be better to have a somewhat clear question, which still relates to the topic.

Comment: @Turing85 So fix it yourself. I don't intend to do anything about it.

Comment: @Turing85  My problem was that I had my instance variables and my local variables mismached. Also, there were some blocks of code that were usless, so I just edited those out.

Comment: @ EJP I would like to apoligize if my title, or my question, didn't make much sense. The problem was that whenever I execcuted the program, the parameters I passes to the constructer Slope returned nothing, and ended up returning 0 - 0 / 0 - 0.

Comment: @JohnStobben instead of editing the error out, it would be better to comment on the error, leaving it in the original question. Therefore, if someone reads this question later on, he/she is still able to retrace the full solution.

Comment: @JohnStobben Your title mentions a compile error which presumably reflects a previous state of the question. At present it doesn't make sense. Instead of just explaining to me, you should FIX IT. At the minimum your title should agree with the content of your question. I suggest you delete this one. It has no permanent value here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your constructor is wrong. It should be like this:

```
public Slope(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    x1 = a;
    x2 = b;
    y1 = c;
    y2 = d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Slope {

```
private int x1;
private int x2;
private int y1;
private int y2;

public Slope(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

    y2 = d;
    y1 = c;
    x2 = b;
    x1 = a;

    System.out.println(x1 - x2 / y1 - y2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Slope slope = new Slope(70, 80, 1, 2);
}
```

}